# Apache mpm-itk not changing user ID

Tags: debian, apache-2.4

Apache 2.4, mpm-itk, Debian 8.
Trying to set up mpm-itk on my server. Added following text to my `<VirtualHost ...>` block:

```
    <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
            AssignUserID bitrix bitrix
            php_value session.save_path /var/www/html/bitrix/tmp
    </IfModule>
```

mpm-itk module is loaded since apache2ctl -M shows it and php_value within it's block works. Still, when I call PHP info it shows the standard *www-data* user. The user and group are present in */etc/passwd* and */etc/group*.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you use mod_php, or any other way to run PHP?

Comment: Yes, I run PHP as apache module.

Comment: What shows in errorlog when you set `LogLevel trace5` within the virtual host block?

Comment: Complains about "Installing seccomp filter failed (probably due to too old kernel); unable to restrict setuid privileges. Error was: Invalid argument"

Comment: And that's probably the reason since apache runs inside an OpenVZ container. Any way to work this around? ISP manager is able to set mpm-itk inside a container, somehow.

Answer (score 0):

So, this issue has been resolved. mpm-itk module in Debian 8 relies on a kernel-based seccomp, which was not explicitly enabled while kernel was built (OpenVZ 2.6.32-042stab108.1).

I found it in strace output from apache, but if you ever encounter an error like this with the following message in apache error log:

> "Installing seccomp filter failed (probably due to too old kernel); unable to restrict setuid privileges. Error was: Invalid argument"

You should know it's not lying ;)